# sum of a function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

what would be the first step to determine sum of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-n^2/4x}.$ I think I should try putting $y=e^{-1/4x}$. Then $y$ changes from $0$ to $1$ and I get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}ny^{n^2}$ but I still don't know what to do with this.. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Use $\cdot$ instead of $*$ next time

Comment: Firstly, what values of $x$ are we looking at?  It doesn't always converge.

Comment: And I'd rather write it as $$\sum\frac n{a^{n^2}}$$ $a=1/y$  Noting this, it is symmetrical ie $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac n{a^{n^2}}=0$$

Comment: I thought that it does converge for every $x \in (0,\infty)$.. or am I wrong?

Comment: @Dominika Well, it obviously doesn't work for $x=0$.

Comment: It does converge in $(0,\infty)$. You can compare it with the integral.

Comment: I note that it is symmetric like that because it reminds me of the riemann zeta function, if you want to look that up.  I doubt it would help here though, but I'm unsure.

Comment: you could try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: with what integral should I compare it?

Comment: Solve $\sum y^{n^2}$ and differentiate with respect to $y$ to get your sum.

Comment: @mlainz whoa, summation by parts, as in integration by parts?!  O_o

Comment: $\int_0^\infty n e^{-n^2/4x} dn$

Comment: @SimpleArt you even have discrete calculus.

Comment: I don't get it.. ii don' think I would be able to integrate it.  besides  $\int e^{-n^2}dn$ looks scary

Comment: Its the standard gaussian integral. You only need to know that it's finite in order to proof convergence.

Comment: but I need the sum of this series not just the proof that it does converge.

Comment: @Dominika Hehe, $\int e^{-n^2}dn$ has no closed form solution in terms of elementary functions.  It implies that this problem probably has no easy closed form solution.

Comment: @SimpleArt The definite integral does have a closed form ($\pi/2$), and its finite, so the sum converges.

Comment: but how is it connected to finding the sum of my series? maybe that integral converges but then what, i'll say that the series must converge as well, but i need an answer to what function it converges

Comment: In which context did you encounter that sum?

Comment: $X_1$ has a prob. density $p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}e^{\frac{-1}{4x}}\mathbf{1}_{x>0}.$ then the density of $S_n$ is $ p_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}n\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}e^{\frac{-n^2}{4x}}.$ and i need to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n$ in order to compute the renewal density. then i will need to integrate it to get the renewal function

Comment: Can't you first integrate and then sum?

Comment: @Dominika I agree, you should integrate first, then sum.  It will probably be easier.  At least the summation doesn't look very pleasing from this standpoint.

Comment: hm interesting.. although then i get anyway to the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-n^2/(4x)}$ which, wolfram says, diverge.. maybe it's simply not possible to do that..

Comment: @Dominika Did you differentiate with respect to $x$?  or $n$?

Comment: no i didn't . What for?

Comment: @Dominika You should be integrating with respect to $n$, just like the summation is respect to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the answer may be found in terms of theta functions.

Firstly, note that

$$x\left(\frac d{dx}\frac{-1}2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{x^{k^2}}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^2}{x^{k^2}}>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac k{x^{k^2}}$$

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2F(x%5E(k%5E2)),%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity) says the answer is

$$\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{x^{k^2}}=\frac14\left(\theta_3(0,\frac1x)-1\right)$$

So... I guess you can get an upper bound?  I don't understand how wolframalpha got the answer, perhaps someone more knowledgeable will be able to explain.

Comment: How did you take that derivative? $\partial_x x^{-k^2} = -k^2 x^{-k^2-1}$

Comment: my future looks bleak if that's the answer :) but thanks!

Comment: @mlainz Well, my bad.  I'll see if I can think of a loop de loop around that.

Comment: @Dominika Wish I could even give you an answer I understood.  :/

Comment: Wolfram just uses the definition of theta function $\vartheta_{3}(z, q)$. I was thinking along the same lines but it appears that it is difficult to get the coefficient $n$ by some manipulation. May be the series in question does not have a closed form in terms of functions already known.

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobi theta function
$\theta(z)$
is defined by
$\theta(z)
=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi m^2z}
=1+2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} e^{-\pi m^2z}
$.

This satisfies 
the functional equation
$\theta(1/z)
=\sqrt{z}\theta(z)
$.

So values for small $z$
determine the values for
large $z$
and vice versa.